# Setting a timeout for av_read_frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to FFMPEG and was trying to do HLS streaming using FFMPEG. When i tried using the function "av_read_frame" it returns a negative value whenever data is not available. Is there some method to make this function wait till some data is received or to make this function wait till a timeout is reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there really isn't. If you look at the simple player [ffplay.c](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/ffplay_8c_source.html#l02878) which comes with FFmpeg, the `read_thread` function basically loops on `av_read_frame` until it returns a non-negative return code. If it returns a negative value, it simply waits for 10ms and retries.