# ffmpeg's av_read_frame will block or not?

Tags: ffmpeg

There is a question posted on StackOverflow that asks if there is any mode to wait until a valid data comes with [av_read_frame](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577642/setting-a-timeout-for-av-read-frame).

My question is the opposite:
Can I be sure that this method will always return with either -1, 0 or 1?

I.e. it will **not** block? In the official docs, there is no mention on this subject.

Some threads also mention setting up an interrupt callback for this purpose.

But I would need a solid non-blocking call which means I can do other tasks during waiting for a network video. If there is no exact way to define if av_read_frame can be set to non-blocking I would go with threads but I'd rather not doing that.

Comment: What is "SF"? Please use words and not abbreviations.

Comment: @szatmary: I mispelled it (wanted to write SO). However there is the link in the same sentence, so it should not have to be confused. However I have corrected it. Could you help me also with my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sources, the `av_read_frame` call eventually goes down to AVIO.

There is the [AVIO_FLAG_NONBLOCK](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_8h.html#aea3131c92c70177e463538e9a6b4308e) flag that you could try to use, but as stated in the documentation it may be silently ignored since it's not implemented for all protocols. You can check the sources of the protocol to see if it's implemented for it.

Another option, to be absolutely sure you won't block, you could implement your own AVIO read function ([example](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2avio_reading_8c-example.html)).