# AVFormatContext: interrupt callback proper usage?

Tags: ffmpeg

AVFormatContext's `interrupt_callback` field is a

> Custom interrupt callbacks for the I/O layer.

It's type is `AVIOInterruptCB`, and it explains in comment section:

> Callback for checking whether to abort blocking functions.
>
> AVERROR_EXIT is returned in this case by the interrupted function. During blocking operations, callback is called with opaque as parameter. If the callback returns 1, the blocking operation will be aborted.
>
> No members can be added to this struct without a major bump, if new elements have been added after this struct in AVFormatContext or AVIOContext.

I have 2 questions:

1. what does the last section means? Especially "without a major bump"?
2. If I use this along with an RTSP source, when I close the input by `avformat_close_input`, the "TEARDOWN" message is being sent out, however it won't reach the RTSP server.

For 2: here is a quick pseudo-code for demo:

```
int pkts = 0;
bool early_exit = false;

int InterruptCallback(void* ctx) {
    return early_exit ? 1 : 0;
}

void main() {
  ctx = avformat_alloc_context
  ctx->interrupt_callback.callback = InterruptCallback;

  avformat_open_input
  avformat_find_stream_info
  pkts=0;
  while(!early_exit) {
    av_read_frame

    if (pkts++ > 100) early_exit=true;
  }

  avformat_close_input
}
```

In case I don't use the interrupt callback at all, TEARDOWN is being sent out, and it also reaches the RTSP server so it can actually tear down the connection. Otherwise, it won't tear down it, and I have to wait until TCP socket times out.

What is the proper way of using this interrupt callback?

Answer (score 1):

1. It means that they are not going to change anything for this structure (AVIOInterruptCB). However, if thats the case it would be in a major bump (major change from 4.4 eg to 5.0)
2. You need to pass a meaningful parameter to void* ctx. Anything that you like so you can check it within the static function. For example a bool that you will set as cancel so you will interrupt the av_read_frame (which will return an AVERROR_EXIT). Usually you pass a class of your decoder context or something similar which also holds all the info that you required to check whether to return 1 to interrupt or 0 to continue the requests properly. A real example would be that you open a wrong rtsp and then you want to open another one (the right one) so you need to cancel your previous requests.

Comment: Re-consider my demo, and think on `early_exit` as a if it was passed as `void* ctx`. Behaviour is the same (no TEARDOWN is being sent out)

Comment: Before avformat_close_input reset your early_exit=false so it will be able to close properly.
Also consider using ctx->interrupt_callback.opaque to pass the parameters to the interrupt function

Comment: One last but very important detail, please confirm this for me: is it 100% sure that `avformat_input_close` can not cause any blocking during tearing down the RTSP connection? If it won't block in any circumstances, it is safe to turn off `early_exit`. Otherwise it might not.

Comment: avformat_close_input, interrupt and teardown are based on the protocol that has been used for ffmpeg. If the case is RTSP (tcp) and you execute avformat_close_input while your interrupting you will not properly close the connection(RST packet).

Comment: I understand this, but what I want to avoid is blocking. Is it possible that `avformat_close_input` would block? In case RTSP (over either TCP or UDP).

Comment: Alright, sorry misunderstood with the blocking. I'm not sure about it... check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59884439/ffmpegs-av-read-frame-will-block-or-not